# Difference between scope in modules and components

Tags: android, dagger-2

What is the difference between the `@Singleton` annotation on Dagger2 `@Component` annotated classes, and `@Provides` annotated methods in modules?

If I have one module in which all methods are annotated with a `@Singleton` annotation, and a component with the same annotation which includes that module, what is the purpose of this?

```
@Singleton
@Component(...)
public interface AppComponent {

    // ...

}
```

And

```
@Provides @Singleton Context provideContext() { return context; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Annotating the `@Provides` method (or the class with an `@Inject` constructor) tells Dagger to implement the actual scoping functionality whereas annotating the component (which is necessary) doesn't have any functionality, but tells Dagger "I allow this component to contain bindings of this scope". Note that you can still have unscoped bindings in a scoped component, but not the other way around.

Answer (score -1):

It's well within the use of a Java annotation to provide documentation to reader, which is what you're probably seeing in your first example.  It's useful there so the reader can know the intended use of the class/interface without having to know the mechanism by which its instance is created or managed.